# How to display Calendar of DateTimePicker to English?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, calendar

How can I change the calendar (of DateTimePicker  of windows Form - c#) to English?

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

This opposite Hebrew...

**Edit:**

After change to English, it still seemed strange:

[image]

Comment: You will need to set the culture info

Comment: @TheLethalCoder How?

Comment: See this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/889834

Comment: @PaulF I change (thank you). But it still seemed strange, I upload a photo.

Comment: Also, make sure your property "RightToLeft" is set properly

Comment: Looks like a `Font` problem. Although I don't think the drop down's font can be easily changed.

Comment: RightToLeft might work, but you might have to set it on the drop down, which will probably require getting the drop down's `Handle` and using `SendMessage(...);` with the `RTL` message. Use Tools->Spy++ to inspect the window and look at the `WindowStyles`.

Comment: Correction, setting the `WindowStyle` using a handle requires using the `SetWindowLong`, not `SendMessage`. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343724/how-do-i-pinvoke-to-getwindowlongptr-and-setwindowlongptr-on-32-bit-platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone had the same problem and solved it by adding an entry to the csproj file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32516707/904156